# Annihilation in algebras derived from a potential

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $k$ be a field and $w$ be a homogeneous (may be twisted) potential of degree $s+1\ge 4$ in the algebra $k<x_1,\dots,x_n>$. This means that $w=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_if_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nf_ix_i$ for some elements $f_i\in k<x_1,\dots,x_n>$ of degree $s$ (or $w=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_if_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nf_i\nu(x_i)$ for some automorphism $\nu$ of $k<x_1,\dots,x_n>$ in the case of a twisted potential). Let us consider the Jacobian algebra $A=k<x_1,\dots,x_n>/(f_1,\dots,f_n)$. My question is the following. Is it possible that there is a nonzero element $g\in A$ such that $x_ig=0$ for all $1\le i\le n$? In fact, I am mainly interested in the case $n=2$, but the general case can be interesting for me too.